# Loop through datatables to find matching values in one column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

I have a datatable which currently displays all the records from a database table.  I am using asp.net and ado.net.  The table is populated by a stored procedure which is simply `select * from table`.  When my view loads the table gets populated with all records.  I want the table to display only related records at a time until those records in the table have been authorised (accepted or rejected and then records are inserted to other tables) or a 'Next' button is clicked.  These records would be grouped by ID.  What ID that shows up first when the view loads just depends on what the first record ID is.

To give an example of data and how I want it displayed:
All records:

```
PageID   AID   Name
1        60    Book1
2        60    Book7
3        50    Book7
4        60    Book8
5        70    Book12
6        70    Book7
```

The first ID is 60(AID) so I would want it to loop through the column, find all that are AID60, display them in the view, once all have been actioned, it would move to AID50 etc etc...

```
PageID   AID   Name
1        60    Book1
2        60    Book7
4        60    Book8
```

What I have currently in the Controller to get the records is:

```
public ActionResult toAction()
{

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstringpath"].ToString());

List<ActionModel> AList = new List<ActionModel>();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Action", con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();


foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
{
    string CurrentAID = dtRow["AID"].ToString();

    if (dtRow["AID"].ToString().Equals(CurrentAID))
   {


AList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows

                 select new ActionModel()
                 {
                     PageID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PageID"]),
                     AID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["AID"]),
                     Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"])

                 }).ToList();
 }
}



return View(AList);
}
```

I am aware the the above code is incorrect as the foreach loop does not work.  The idea would be to 
Get the AID of the first record in the table, loop through the rest of the column looking for the same AID and add all records to the list to display to the view.  Once actioned in the view the next AID will populate.  (I have the Accept/Reject/Next buttons already)

I just need to get the foreach working correctly to only show out one AID at a time.  I will not be passing an AID as a parameter so the likes of `Select * from Action where AID = @AID` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionModel toAction()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstringpath"].ToString());

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Action", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    return dt.Select("AID = 60").ToList<ActionModel>();
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Sina I would need to know the ID in order to do it this way though? The idea is that I dont know what the first ID would be, so I would need it to identify the first ID then loop through the column, find matching IDs and add all to a list to display to the view

Comment: @Deirdreso12 sorry. I don't understand

Comment: instead of setting it to a certain AID like above, I need it to set the value to whatever the AID is in the first row...this will constantly change.  So I would need to set the value of AID in the first datarow to a variable then pass that variable through to dt.Select() to itirrate through the rows and find matching rows with that value AID.  Like I have shown in my example above.  The data I gave above is mock data, the table I have holds thousands of records and I wouldnt know any AID.  Something like this(doesnt work)

Comment: DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
            string rowValue = row["UID"].ToString();
            return dt.Select(rowValue).ToList<AuthoriseModel>();